# How to find the Fourier transform when it is in the form of $\frac j\pi$ [$\frac{1}{(t-3)^2-1}$+$\frac{1}{(t+3)^2-1}$]

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

So as the title suggests, I can compute fourier transforms in basic forms using the known properties. But how would one attempt to do this? How do I compute the integral? Or is there a pattern/pair that I could use?
The equation is as follows x(t) = $\frac j\pi$ [$\frac{1}{(t-3)^2-1}$+$\frac{1}{(t+3)^2-1}$]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use fractions decomposition then
$$
\dfrac{j}{\pi}\left(\dfrac{1}{(t-3)^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{(t+3)^2-1}\right)
=
\dfrac{j}{2\pi}\left(\dfrac{1}{t-4}-\dfrac{1}{t-2}+\dfrac{1}{t+2}-\dfrac{1}{t+4}\right)
$$
and apply [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)
$${\cal F}\left(\dfrac{1}{t-a}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{t-a}e^{-jwt}dt=j\pi\operatorname{sgn}(w)e^{-jwa}$$
which the integral calculate with [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).